# how to save two datepicker data

Tags: android, datepicker

I tried to use the code that has been answer here

[How can I create a custom dialog with two datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691030/how-can-i-create-a-custom-dialog-with-two-datepicker)

However, after i successfully call the 2 datepicker, i do not know how to enter my selected date to my text view. I tried to use

```
public void onDateSet(CustomViewCallback customView, int startYear, int startMonth, int startDay, int endYear, int endMonth,int endDay) {
    Datestart.setText(startYear+ startMonth+ startDay);
}
```

but it does not work, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Seems you need to convert `startYear` , `startMonth` and `startDay` to `string`. I believe `setText` return `string`. What error you get if you run that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `Datestart.setText(startYear+ startMonth+ startDay);` with `Datestart.setText(startYear+"/"+ startMonth+"/"+ startDay);`.
or

```
Datestart.setText(startYear+""+ startMonth+""+ startDay); to convert value in string.
```

Comment: ya right, we have to add between all the value. Datestart.setText(startYear+""+ startMonth+""+ startDay);

Answer (score 0):

`TextView.setText()` has an overload that takes an `int` parameter that refers to a `String` resource. In your case, `startYear+ startMonth+ startDay` will produce an `int` value. If the resource that matches is not available, you will get a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

If you just want a simple text date, try the following:

```
Datestart.setText(startYear + "/" + startMonth + "/" + startDay);
```

Or, if you want it more like what you seem to expect from your code:

```
Datestart.setText(String.valueOf(startYear) + String.valueOf(startMonth) + String.valueOf(startDay));
```